# Multiple string search with InStr in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am checking whether a Name textbox starts with Mr. Mrs. Ms. etc.

I created a function but I am not able to compare more than one string.

Here is my code.

```
'Checking whether name is starts with Mr./Mrs./Ms./Dr. or not
If Not FindString(LCase(Me.gname.Value), LCase("Mr")) Then
    MsgBox "Consumer Name Starts with Mr./Mrs./Ms./Dr. Check Consumer Name"
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End If

'Here is the Find String function i created
Function FindString(strCheck As String, strFind As String) As Boolean
    Dim intPos As Integer

    intPos = 0
    intPos = InStr(strCheck, strFind)
    FindString = intPos > 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass strFind as group of strings seperated by a delimiter ex:-

```
FindString(LCase(Me.gname.Value), LCase("Mr;Mrs;Ms;Dr"))
```

Now split them and compare using a loop.

```
Arr = Split(strFind,";")
Flag = 0

For Each str in Arr    
  If InStr(strCheck, str) > 0 Then
  Flag = 1    
  End If
Next
If Flag = 1 Then
  FindString = True
Else
  FindString = False
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass a list of tokens to search for using a `ParamArray` and loop each looking for a match.

You can use `vbTextCompare` to enforce case sensitivity.

Remember that *starts with* is different from *contains*.

```
'// you can pass as many prefixes as you like
If StringStarts(Me.gname.Value, "Mr", "Mrs", "Dr", "Supreme Commander", "Capt.") Then
    MsgBox "Consumer Name Starts with Mr./Mrs./Ms./Dr. Check Consumer Name"

... 

Function StringStarts(strCheck As String, ParamArray anyOf()) As Boolean
    Dim item As Long
    For item = 0 To UBound(anyOf)
        If InStr(1, strCheck, anyOf(item), vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            StringStarts = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Or better with a `RegEx` to allow optional `.` and not match `Mruku`

```
StringStarts(Me.gname.Value, "Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr")

...

Function StringStarts(strCheck As String, options As String) As Boolean
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "^(" & options & ")\.*\b"

        StringStarts = .Test(strCheck)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: @Alex K. Good! I like the solution with the regular expression. But what if we have more than 20 strings to search? I think it is not sweetable to write them all.

Answer (score 1):

This is my version of [@AlexK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246342/alex-k) [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24972568/5079799). While it solved the OP's original problem I wanted to share a more generalized answer for others to benefit from.

Here is how I used the Function:

```
Public Sub InString_Test()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim rcell As Range, rng As Range
Set rng = WS.Range("A1:A" & WS.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
For Each rcell In rng.Cells

If InStrFunc(Range(rcell.Address), "TEST", "CAT") Then
   MsgBox "String Found in " & rcell.Address
End If

Next rcell

End Sub

Function InStrFunc(strCheck As String, ParamArray anyOf()) As Boolean
    Dim item As Long
    For item = 0 To UBound(anyOf)
        If InStr(1, strCheck, anyOf(item), vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            InStrFunc = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Super. Works straight outta the box.