# Search with InStr function for multiple words in a string

Tags: vba

I have a problem finding one or more keywords within a string.

I've been helped on the way by https://stackoverflow.com/a/24972568. The code limits the search to the first word in the string.
It is pointed out in the answer:

> Remember that *starts with* is different from *contains*.

I tried changing the parts of the code that uses `StringStarts` to `Contains`.

```vb
If StringStarts(Me.gname.Value, "Mr", "Mrs", "Dr", "Supreme Commander", "Capt.") Then
    MsgBox "Consumer Name Starts with Mr./Mrs./Ms./Dr. Check Consumer Name"
    '... 
    
Function StringStarts(strCheck As String, ParamArray anyOf()) As Boolean
    Dim item As Long
    For item = 0 To UBound(anyOf)
        If InStr(1, strCheck, anyOf(item), vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            StringStarts = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear.. do you want to be able to search the keyword *anywhere* in the string? Or do you want to be able to find all the keywords in the string (and not just stop at the first matching keyword)?

Comment: You are right. I actually want to be able to establish if there are none of the keywords, one of the keywords and whether the keyword occurs more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringContains()` functions returns how many of the strings passed through `anyOf` array is contained in the first string passed as argument:

```
Function StringContains2(strCheck As String, ParamArray anyOf()) As Long
    Dim item As Long
    For item = 0 To UBound(anyOf)
        If InStr(1, strCheck, anyOf(item), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then Exit For
    Next
    StringContains2 = item
End Function
```

to be used like:

```
Sub main()
    Dim msg As String, strng As String

    strng = Me.gname.Value 
    Select Case StringContains2(strng, "Mr", "Mrs", "Dr", "Supreme Commander", "Capt.")
        Case 0
            msg = "there was no keyword in the string"
        Case Is > 1
            msg = "there were two or more keywords in the string"
    End Select        
    If msg <> "" Then MsgBox msg, vbCritical    
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works as I initially intended. As it seems, however, I haven't been too clear with my question.

From the question from the user NvJ, I have realised that I need to establish if there are none of the keywords, one of the keywords AND whether the keyword occurs more than once. As I have clarified my question to the user "Nvj", I assume that he will answer this? (I am not trying to put two guys to work)

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for you for your updated reply. 

I haven't explained my issue and question clear and correct.

What I want to do is the following:

1. Display one specific error message if there are no keywords in the string.
2. Display another error message if there are two or more keywords in the string.

I thus want to prevent that the keyword doesn't appear at all  and prevent that the keywords appear more than once.

I apologize for not being very good at being clear.
Christian

Comment: It works perfectly! How do you want me to show my appreciation?

Comment: accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: `StringContains2` is exiting on the first non-match, and otherwise returning the position of the match. So if `InStr` returns `2` it doesn't mean it found it 2 times, but that it found it in position 2.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question/answer is old, but I found it looking for "VBA string contains one of many strings" so others might as well.
The accepted answer taught me about `ParamArray` which I've never used, but the code also isn't doing what it says, as `StringContains2` returns the **position** of the first match found, and if the first word (e.g. "Mr") isn't found, then none of the other words are even checked.

For example, if I set `strng = "Dr Mrs Mrs Capt. Supreme Commander Dave"` then `main` says "there were no keywords" when I'm guessing you'd want it to return `5`.

There's also an issue with using `InStr` that if you're looking for "Mr" and the name is "Mr Imram Dave" it will find "Mr" in two places since it uses `vbTextCompare` which ignores case. Although in this code, it would only return `1` since it only checks each item in `anyOf` once, and InStr returns the first position found, not a count of occurrences.

If you want an error message for zero or more than one, that means you want to ensure that the name contains **one and only one** of the title prefixes, and probably regardless of whether it's "Mr" or "Mr." (but while considering case and not flagging anything incorrectly) so this could really be quite complicated to get right.

But you can use the combination of `Ubound` and `Split` to get the number of occurrences of one string in another, so here's my modification:

```
Function StringContains(stringToCheck As String, stringsToCheckFor As Variant) As Long
    Dim item As Long
    Dim occurrencesFound As Integer
    For item = 0 To UBound(stringsToCheckFor)
        occurrencesFound = occurrencesFound + UBound(Split(stringToCheck, stringsToCheckFor(item), , vbBinaryCompare))
    Next
    StringContains = occurrencesFound
End Function

Sub Test_StringContains()
    Dim msg As String, test As String
    Dim titles As Variant
    titles = Array("Mr ", "Mr.", "Mrs ", "Mrs.", "Dr ", "Dr.", "Supreme Commander", "Capt ", "Capt.")

    test = "Mr Mrs. Mrs Dr Supreme Commander Dave"
    Debug.Print "Input: " & test & " has " & StringContains(test, titles) & " occurrences."
    'Input: Mr Mrs. Mrs Dr Supreme Commander Dave has 5 occurrences.
    
    test = "Mr Commander Dave"
    Debug.Print "Input: " & test & " has " & StringContains(test, titles) & " occurrences."
    'Input: Mr Commander Dave has 1 occurrences.
    
    test = "MrDave"
    Debug.Print "Input: " & test & " has " & StringContains(test, titles) & " occurrences."
    'Input: MrDave has 0 occurrences.
    
 End Sub
```