# VBScript function to read multiple strings not working properly

Tags: arrays, string, vbscript, hp-uft

I have a function to read multiple string that I copied from another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972335/multiple-string-search-with-instr-function-in-vba).

I have the whole document that I need in a string name strResult, my intention is to compare only the fields on the strList, and find them in the strResult.

This is the function:

```
Function FindString(strCheck,strFind) 
    Arr = Split(strResult,",")
    Flag = 0
```

And I call it like this: Call FindString(strResult,strList)

```
For Each str in Arr    
  If InStr(strCheck, str) > 0 Then
  Flag = 1    
     Reporter.ReportEvent micPass,"Field Found","Field:"&str&" was found"
  Else
  Flag = 0
      Reporter.ReportEvent micFail,"Field not Found","Field:"&str&" was not found"
  End If
Next
If Flag = 1 Then
  FindString = True
  Reporter.ReportEvent micPass,"Field Found","Field"&str&"was found"
Else
  FindString = False
  Reporter.ReportEvent micFail,"Field not found","Field"&str&"was not found"
End If
```

It should return fail when the fields are not found, but it just ignores them, The list of string is on a variable that contains something like "field1,"&_"field2", the main problem is that even if "field3" is not in the strList, it will display it as found, and I only want it to take the fields that are on the strList not all of the strResult string

Comment: can you give a realistic example of both `strCheck` and `strFind` ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the function by splitting the list of values too, like this

```
Arr = Split(strCheck,",")
Arr2 = Split(strFind,",")
Flag = 0

For Each str in Arr  
    For Each str2 in Arr2
        If InStr(str, str2) > 0 Then
            Flag = 1    
            Reporter.ReportEvent micPass,"Field "&str2&" Found","Field:"&str&" was found"
            Exit For
        End If

    Next
```